# Appending a value from one table into another based on a criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables that I'm trying to join in a particular way. One is a simple tibble that provides a HEX color and its category that it is associated with:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

colors <- tibble(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  Colors = c("#0079c0", "#cc9900", "#252525", "#c5120e"))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
   Category Colours
     <chr>   <chr>
1        A #0079c0
2        B #cc9900
3        C #252525
4        D #c5120e
```

I have another tibble that lists the categories both as rows and columns, and those appear in a specific way:

```
Main_Table <- tibble(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     A = c(NA, "A", NA, NA),
                     B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
                     C = c(NA, "C", NA, NA),
                     D = c("D", "D", NA, NA))

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Category     A     B     C     D
     <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>
1        A  <NA>    NA  <NA>     D
2        B     A    NA     C     D
3        C  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>
4        D  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>
```

I want to join the color into the main table based on whether its corresponding category is present under the variable that bears its name. For example, let's say that if I want category D's color to be included, I'd end up with the below:

```
Main_Table_Goal <- tibble(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     A = c(NA, "A", NA, NA),
                     B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
                     C = c(NA, "C", NA, NA),
                     D = c("D", "D", NA, NA),
                     color = c("#c5120e", "#c5120e", NA, NA))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
    Category     A     B     C     D    color
      <chr>  <chr> <lgl>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1        A   <NA>    NA   <NA>     D  #c5120e
2        B      A    NA      C     D  #c5120e
3        C   <NA>    NA   <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
4        D   <NA>    NA   <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
```

How do I achieve this using `dplyr`? I've been trying with `*_join` and other tricks, but I've not gotten anywhere.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I'd like to eventually include this in a function, so ideally the code can be flexible to accommodate any number of categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `match`

```
Main_Table %>% 
         mutate(color = colors$Colors[match(D, colors$Category)])
# A tibble: 4 × 6
#  Category     A     B     C     D   color
#     <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>
#1        A  <NA>    NA  <NA>     D #c5120e
#2        B     A    NA     C     D #c5120e
#3        C  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
#4        D  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: I was just playing with `match` now.

Comment: The `match` function is exactly what was eluding me... Thanks!

Comment: Given this match idea, `mutate_at(vars(A:D),funs(color = Colors[match(., Category)]))` is the way to revise my idea, isn't it?

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I just updated my idea. Up to now, I thought funs gotta take functions like min, max, replace, etc. `color = Colors[match(., Category)])` somehow does not look like a function to me. I guess funs contain whatever operations you need, and as long as your outcome fits in the data frame you work with.

Comment: @akrun Hey, how have you been doing? Since the beginning of this year, I am not catching up with SO well. What's happening these days?

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for the comments.  I was on a business call, so couldn't answer your comment earlier.  It is all good and in full swing.  I really miss your inputs.

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I still have lots to learn from you and others. I have been going through a rough time. I now got some time for learning R, but I am lacking motivation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how many categories you have in your data. But if you have only four (i.e., A, B, C, and D), the following would be one way. I wanted to work with one data frame. So I initially merged the two data frames. I converted B in logical to character since I wanted to use `mutate_at()`. Then, I replaced the four categories with the four colors. Finally, I removed `Colors` and converted B to logical.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(Main_Table, colors) %>%
mutate(B = as.character(B)) %>%
mutate_at(vars(A:D),
          funs(color = recode(., A = Colors[1],
                                 B = Colors[2],
                                 C = Colors[3],
                                 D = Colors[4]))) %>%
select(-Colors) %>%
mutate(B = as.logical(B))
```

Given akrun's idea, you can do the following. As long as you can tell how many category you have, you just specify the columns in `vars()`. If all columns are in character, no need to convert logical to character.

```
left_join(Main_Table, colors) %>%
mutate(B = as.character(B)) %>%
mutate_at(vars(A:D),funs(color = Colors[match(., Category)])) %>%
select(-Colors) %>%
mutate(B = as.logical(B)) 


#  Category     A     B     C     D A_color B_color C_color D_color
#     <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
#1        A  <NA>    NA  <NA>     D    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> #c5120e
#2        B     A    NA     C     D #0079c0    <NA> #252525 #c5120e
#3        C  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#4        D  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that this is actually part of a function, where eventually I'd like to have this done dynamically, so the number of categories could vary.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dynamic solution where you set the color parameter once at the top:

```
target_category <- 'D'  # set color
target_category_table <- Main_Table %>%
    select_(target_category) %>%
    left_join(colors %>%
                  filter(Category == target_category) %>%
                  setNames(c(target_category, 'color')))
goal_table <- Main_Table %>%
    bind_cols(select(target_category_table, color))
goal_table
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  Category     A     B     C     D   color
     <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1        A  <NA>    NA  <NA>     D #c5120e
2        B     A    NA     C     D #c5120e
3        C  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
4        D  <NA>    NA  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: You may have just saved my bacon. Thank you sir. :)

Comment: @Phil Welcome. Be careful when binding the `target_category_table` and `goal_table` back together as they may not align correctly in scenarios other than this one. You probably should keep the `Category` variable in both tables and join on that rather than using `bind_cols`. Let me know if you'd like me to edit the solution accordingly.